# How do I stop Mongoose from logging to stdout?

Tags: c++, logging, mongoose-web-server

I'm embedding [Mongoose](http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) in my application, but it logs everything to stdout.

```
char const* options[] = {
  "listening_ports", boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(port).c_str(),
  nullptr
};

context = ::mg_start(&callback,
                     reinterpret_cast<void*>(&router),
                     options);
```

It outputs stuff like:

```
*** 1339802127.0x7fff7922c960.mg_start.4192: [listening_ports] -> [8000]
*** 1339802127.0x7fff7922c960.mg_start.4202: Setting default: [cgi_pattern] -> [**.cgi$|**.pl$|**.php$]
*** 1339802127.0x7fff7922c960.mg_start.4202: Setting default: [authentication_domain] -> [mydomain.com]
*** 1339802127.0x7fff7922c960.mg_start.4202: Setting default: [ssi_pattern] -> [**.shtml$|**.shtm$]
*** 1339802127.0x7fff7922c960.mg_start.4202: Setting default: [enable_directory_listing] -> [yes]
*** 1339802127.0x7fff7922c960.mg_start.4202: Setting default: [index_files] -> [index.html,index.htm,index.cgi]
```

How can I prevent Mongoose from logging to stdout?

Comment: It does that because you've compiled it in debug mode. Look for `#define DEBUG_TRACE` in mongoose.c.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `-DDEBUG` from the compilation flags.